# How do I read MacBook pro (2018) Thunderbolt ports using Python?

Tags: python, macos, usb

I want to program a little test program to test the operation of a self-assembled Geiger-counter kit (https://mightyohm.com/blog/products/geiger-counter/). The Geiger-counter kit comes with a standard USB 2.0 serial connector which I want to connect through a Vivanco 34295 USB-C to USB hub (https://www.vivanco.de/Startseite/Produkte/Computer/USB-Verbindungen/USB-Typ-C-Verbindungen/vivanco-45387-usb-type-c-8482-cardreader-hub-weiss.html?id=8mfC65B7).

I am working on a MacBook Pro 14,1 (2018) running under MacOS 10.15.2 (Catalina)

My idea is to write a little Python program performing read operations, similar to

```
import sys
import serial


ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyuc', 19200, timeout=5)

# listen for the input, exit if nothing received in timeout period
while True:
    line = ser.readline()
    if len(line) == 0:
        print("Time out! Exit.\n")
        sys.exit()
    print(line)
```

which does not work - at least it does not read anything...

Currently I don't have a clue how to proceed here, Google searches did not get me anywhere.